# Django - absolute path image not showing up

Tags: django, image, django-templates, absolute-path

I am trying to display an image with the src equal to an absolute path. This is what I did in the template

```
    <img src="/home/userName/Documents/app/userPhotos/1/uploadedPhotos/imageName.png" alt="" />
```

and it does not show up. I'm positive that it is the correct absolute path. Is there anything I need to do, say in my settings.py file, to be able to use absolute paths? Do I need to

```
import os
```

in my template?

Edit:

Just in case it helps, when I run the server and go to the url which calls the template (/displayImages/, this is what it says in my terminal:

```
[23/Feb/2014 12:07:27] "GET /displayImages/ HTTP/1.1" 200 413
[23/Feb/2014 12:07:27] "GET /home/userName/Documents/app/userPhotos/1/uploadedPhotos/imageName.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2993
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Daniel wrote in his answer, you should not use absolute path for any content on your website. This leads to a security concern and to a not **working statement** position. When the browser sees /absolute/path/img.png, it searches for this path **starting at the root of your website**. So, this can become /home/userName/Documents/app/absolute/path/img.png, which doesn't exists.

The right way is:

- Read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) :)
- Add (or use) the settings.STATIC_URL defined in `settings.py`. The default path is the folder static/ in your app folder.
- Use `{% load staticfiles %}` and `{{ static "relative/path/file.ext" }}` in your template

Comment: hm right, I have my static files set up. The thing is, I'm creating an image hosting app where all users do is upload a bunch of images, so I figured it would be better if I saved the images in a folder outside of the app directory, wouldn't that be better? Or will it not make a difference in terms of performance or anything else important if my app directory / folder has over, say 10,000 large jpeg files uploaded by the users?

Comment: You can put your static files where you want. As long as you set the settings.STATIC_URL and you actually use it in your template, it will run as it should. As for performance, I'm pretty sure it won't change anything.

Comment: hm okay two questions. -1- my STATIC_URL is just /static/, I define where Django should look for static files in STATICFILES_DIRS.. isn't that how it is supposed to be done? and -2- so is it okay if my static folder is not in the project directory? So for example, if my STATICFILES_DIRS is /home/static/, is that okay? Or is that also not preferred and will it also lead to security concerns?

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` is used to tell Django to search your static files in more than one folder. In your case, you know where they will be. 1) and 2) Yes, you define one place and you use it, really, where you want. No, this is not a security concern; the user will only see the relative path. Test and you will see :)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use a file path in your template? You should be using a URL, absolute or relative: the address where that image is being served from.

Comment: I'm creating an image hosting app where all users do is upload a bunch of images, so I figured it would be better if I saved the images in a folder outside of the app directory, wouldn't that be better? Or will it not make a difference in terms of performance or anything else important if my app directory / folder has over, say 10,000 large jpeg files uploaded by the users?